# Order of results of the_category

Tags: wordpress

A template I'm using is calling [`the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category) to list the categories which a post belongs. It's ordering them by name. Is there a way to reverse the order by ID category?

Answer (score 4):

Just replace your `the_category(' ')` with this

```
$cats=get_the_category();
$cid=array();
foreach($cats as $cat)  { $cid[]=$cat->cat_ID; }
    $cid=implode(',', $cid);
    foreach((get_categories('orderby=name&include='.$cid)) as $category) { // notice orderby
        echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->cat_ID).'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a> '; // keep a space after </a> as seperator 
    }
```

You can use **orderby** value one of the following

```
id
name - default
slug
count
term_group
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am trying to get the categories to print out with the parent category first and then the child category. I tried orderby term_group, and it seems to work. Is this the way to get it to do what I want to? In searching the internet, I have found some people saying not to use term_group and nothing about what term_group actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the_category hasn't order by functionality. You need to go to **wp-includes/category-template.php** There is a function called "get_the_terms" in that file.In this function there is a line like `$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $id, $taxonomy );`

wp_get_object_terms can take extra argument for args.You can edit here liike below;

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC');
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $id, $taxonomy, $args);
```

You can modify $args according to your needs

Hope this helps